# jquery client side paging on an associative multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, paging

I'm coding a job portal where I have to bring data from an api. I need to load 1000 of jobs from this site every time. To make the system effective I have loaded 9 jobs for the first time when page loaded and then load the other remaining jobs and these 9 jobs in a java-script array via ajax (jQuery) call.

What I need to do is to apply the paging on the array and maintain the first loaded 9 jobs (since they will be first 9 in the array of 1000 jobs) on the first page. I hope this makes sense.

PS: I'm showing jobs in divs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Or do you want general advice about how to structure code to do that sort of thing?

Comment: @nnnnnn actually i need to know some shortcut to avoid possible bugs that might arrive in custom written code. some jquery plugin .
PS: I know the structure code and logic for what and how to do, Since the application is for a client I want it to be bug free

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: it is a general question, I don't think any code will help you understanding this question

Comment: This Q&A site is about code-specific questions, if you're more inclined to the theory of how to do things, [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is the place. I'd also note that [SO isn't your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/186879) and there are quite a few jQuery pagination plugins out there. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the jobs data in a jobs array. Then you can always pick the elements to show depending on what the page the user selects.

It would be as simple as

```
var startIndex = selectedPage * PageSize;
var endIndex = startIndex  + PageSize;
```

An array of objects should be perfect for the job.

Comment: looking for some jquery to do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to (pseudo) paginate via JQuery the results in page this could you help:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FqxhT/)